# Pagination using Display tag in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, display, jsp-tags

i an writing code for Pagination using display tag in jsp but can anyone tell me how i can display Empdao.java list in Display tag in display tag.

Empdao.java

```
public class Empdao {  

    public static List<Emp> getRecords(int start,int total){  
        List<Emp> list=new ArrayList<Emp>();  
        try{  
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");  
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/employee","root","root");  
            PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("select * from employee limit "+(start-1)+","+total);  
            ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();  
            while(rs.next()){  
                Emp e=new Emp();  
                e.setId(rs.getInt("ID"));  
                e.setName(rs.getString("Name"));  
                e.setSalary(rs.getFloat("Salary"));  
                list.add(e);  
            }  
            con.close();  
        }catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);}  
        return list;  
    }  
}
```

please tell me how i can display list in display tag.
thanks in advance

Display tag

```
<display:table name=list export="true">
  <display:column property="id" />
  <display:column property="name" />
  <display:column property="salary" />
</display:table>
```

but it's not working, please tell me where i'm wrong.

Comment: Hi, list should be available in session or in the request scope. ensure that it is available , it should work.

Comment: @MuthuvelP thanks,  also added <taglib> and jar problem solved

Comment: This issue resolved thanks for reply @MuthuvelP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added  tag library and related library files, issue resolved.

taglib-

> **<%@ taglib uri="http://displaytag.sf.net" prefix="display" %>**

following jars-

> displaytag-1.2.jar
>
> displaytag-export-poi-1.2.jar
>
> displaytag-portlet-1.2.jar